# Full git history of every commit for a branch

Tags: git

I think I'm missing something fundamental about git.

I have a branch M that has tons of development branches merged into it.

I have a tag on M - "`mtag`" and I want to get every commit/comment pair on M since a start date that includes all the commits on the development branches. (minus the ones on an `arbitary` some-another-branch)

Currently I do it by looking at merge commits, getting the parent and the branch that was merged in and retrieving the history for each development branch (since a start date) this way - but I'm sure there must be a simpler way, via `git log`, I can't be the only one doing this.

I've tried `--full-history`, `--no-merges` etc.

It's slightly complicated as this code is run on the live repo directly that has all the branches via a web interface, but thats under control.

What am I missing ?

Typically I do this:

```
cd /repo/xxx.git
/usr/bin/git log --since="2016/12/9"` --date-order --name-status --`format='commit:%H%nauthor:%an%ndate:%ci%nsubject:%s%nnotes:%N%nbody:%b%nparent:%P%n' "mtag" --not some-other-branch 2>&1
```

I can live without the `some-other-branch` if necessary, by fetching that myself and removing them.

Comment: `git log` without any options will display all commits that are in the current branch, including thos on other branches that has been merged. So you should'nt have to specify anything else to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, think I was having a brain failure, not sure I got into this state, many of the commits I thought I was missing were before the 'since' date even though I thought they were after.